# How can I use Control+` (grave accent) as my escape character for screen?

Tags: linux, bash, gnu-screen, escape-characters

I've been trying to think of an escape character to use for screen that isn't already used by any of the programs I use, and I've settled on Ctrl+`. The default Ctrl+a is unacceptable for me because it's the bash shortcut for jumping to the beginning of a line. However, when I add the following to `~/.screenrc`:

```
escape ^``
```

screen does not seem to recognize Ctrl+` as the escape key. Is there any way to use the combination Ctrl+`, and if not, does anyone have a suggestion for an escape key that isn't used in many progams?

Comment: If you're a `vi`/`vim` user, you could combine the best (worst?) of both worlds and make your escape `Ctrl+Esc`. But for ease-of-use, my fingers seem to enjoy `Ctrl+h`, because I use both hands *and* keep them on the home row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea that may work: in a normal terminal outside of screen, run cat and type `` Ctrl-` `` and see what you get.  For me it is `^@`.  Then in screen use `` escape ^@` `` and now `` Ctrl-` `` should work as your command key.

Comment: Yes, for me it was `^@` also, and adding "escape ^@`" to .screenrc worked. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: @Fredrick Note that there are apparently multiple keys which generate `^@`, e.g. `Ctrl-2` for me.  This shouldn't be a problem since if the terminal emulator can't distinguish them nothing running inside it would be expected to - just be aware you may have multiple command keys with that mapping.